# Insert Multi Row Script Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have written a google sheet script for addding single row code below:

```
//input values
function SubmitData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry"); // entry sheet
var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); // data sheet

var values = [[ formS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("C4").getValue(),    
                formS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("E4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("F4").getValue(),                
                formS.getRange("G4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("H4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("I4").getValue(),    
                formS.getRange("J4").getValue(),
                formS.getRange("K4").getValue()]];    

dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,2,1,10).setValues(values);  
}
```

But I want to add multi-row if **B5** or **C5** data exist.

**The Sheet Where I Add Row Data:**
[image: SHEET WHERE I ADD ROW DATA]

**The Result I Want in the Data Sheet:**
[image: RESULT I WANT IN DATA SHEET]

Answer (score 0):

Do do that, you need to iterate the rows and "patch" missing values by copying the value in the same column in the first row. Try this:

```
function copyEntriesToDataSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const [firstRow, ...furtherRows] = ss.getRange('Entry!A4:K').getValues();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  targetSheet.appendRow(firstRow);
  furtherRows.forEach(row => {
    if (row.join('')) {
      targetSheet.appendRow(row.map((value, index) => String(value) ? value : firstRow[index]));
    }
  });
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).